# Google directions api mvc asp.net how to implement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I need to use webservices for my aplication, and one of the solutions I found was google directions API in order to generate a route from one direction to another and then store it into a table.

I looked up on the google direction api documentation but only said how to use it. I want to know what  I need to do in order to implement it in my project.

Comment: What's the difference in "use it" vs "implement it"?

Comment: Huh? What do you need that the docs don't tell you?

Comment: It says that It uses an url in and uses an output and pattern and things like that. I want to know what do I need to do in terms of the project (create a model, where to reference that url, any controller needed, things like that. I know nothing about webservices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests) tells you that you have to make simple HTTP requests to use the Google Directions API.

To send a requests to

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=bern&destination=zurich
```

use a web client like this:

```
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=bern&destination=zurich";
var client = new WebClient();
var content = client.DownloadString(url);
```